# How can I make UINavigationBars transparent within UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have `UISplitViewController` with two `UINavigationControllers`. How can I make it transparent?

I think it is not transparent because of some bar of split view controller.

[image]

And finally it looks like this:

[image]

which is not what I need to get;)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, your SplitViewController, view should contain 3 views: first one will be this gray bar. So in your SplitViewController subclass you can do something like this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if let potentialBarView = view.subviews.first {
        if round(potentialBarView.bounds.height) == 64 {
            potentialBarView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering why SplitViewController is making such subview each time it is showing up, maybe someone has idea, I don't. But this workaround is working perfectly.

Comment: ha ha lets do it;) but you need to know that it wont work for iphone in landscape mode. Bar is not equal to 64 there;)